# imagemagick's import under osx

Tags: macos, imagemagick, screenshot

I am using import to mouse-select a screenshot, and under linux it works ok with `import <filename>`.

Under osx instead (snowleopard), the same command hasnt any effect: the terminal remains with the cursor blinking, the mouse doesnt change shape suggesting that I select a region, and I can only ^C it.

Using it instead so:

```
import -window root a.png
```

it works perfectly.

Any hint?

Answer (score 3):

This is a quirky thing with X11, Imagemagick, and Snow Leopard. The `import` command hangs and waits until you invoke the [X display server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System). If you do not have [X11 "XQuartz"](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac) running, or installed, you would experience the same behavior your observing. Here are some examples of X server running on top of OS X's display manager.

```sh
convert x: -window root desktop # same as import
```

[image: X11 desktop on Snow Leopard]

Notice you can see the running xlogo application from the X server, but pixel garbage form the non-X display manager.

To capture a single window, I'll need to run the following command, switch to an X application, and finally select a window.

```sh
convert x: app.png
```

[image: X application]

### Hints:

Why use Imagemagick at all? Snow leopard ships with a `screencapture` utility. Checkout the [manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/10.6/man1/screencapture.1.html?useVersion=10.6). Simply updated your script to identify which utility to use.

```sh
IMPORT_BIN=$(which screencapture)
if [ -z "$IMPORT_BIN" ]; then
  # Not on OS X, use IM's import command
  IMPORT_BIN="import"
else
  # On OS X, don't trust X display system
  IMPORT_BIN="$IMPORT_BIN -wS" 
fi
$(IMPORT_BIN) filename.png
```

For the most part, most of this issues have been resolved already. Ensure that you have the latest versions of X11, Imagemagick, and start making plans to migrate off OS X 10.6.